# Why am I not getting the curious badge?

Tags: support, badges

It is showing that I have asked questions with positive votes on 7 different days but still I am not getting the curious badge? What is the reason for this?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You also have **seven deleted questions**. (You can't find them using search since you have less than 10k rep, but you will be able to see them if you're given the links. Let me know if you want me to provide links so you can check.) So [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/214582/31394), for example, "doesn't count" towards your Curious badge because you also asked a deleted question on the same day.

Of those seven deleted questions, **six have negative score** and **three are closed**. So using the metric in [TLC's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12621/31394), your record is

```
(TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions = (19 - 6 - 3 - 7) / 19 = 3/19
```

which is not more than half. Ironically, if you just undeleted all your self-deleted questions, then I think you would get the badge! (Not that I'm necessarily recommending you do that, since at least some of those closed self-deleted questions really should be deleted.)

Comment: Ah forgot about the 10k baseline for the search.

Answer (score 4):

If you track the badge on your profile page it will say something like:

> need positive question record

Presumably you have some deleted questions and they are negatively scored and/or closed. You can find your deleted questions with this search [`deleted:yes is:q`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3Ayes+is%3Aq) (when you have 10k rep), it will only return your own deleted content as you can't search other user's deleted content.

To fix this you either have to edit and undelete some questions to fix them up or just keep asking more questions until you have a "positive question record". The [following information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/345161), specifically the last part, is important here:

> - There are four different counts that are tracked when calculating the criteria for this badge:
>
>   - Positive: Number of questions asked on this day that have a score greater than 0.
>   - Negative: Number of questions asked on this day that have a score less than 0.
>   - Closed: Number of questions asked on this day that are currently closed and the current closure date occurred within 60 days of being asked.
>   - Deleted: Number of questions asked on this day that are currently deleted and the current deletion date occurred within 60 days of being asked.
> - Any day that has at least one Positive question *and* also has no Negative, Closed, or Deleted questions counts as a "qualifying day" which increments the counter.
> - A positive question record means you don't have too many Closed, Negative, or Deleted questions overall. The formula is `(TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5`. Questions that qualify as Negative *and* Closed *and* Deleted count three times in this calculation!

Comment: "*when you have 10k rep*" - OP is quite far from that at the moment ...

Comment: @thelethalcarrot what is the meaning of the image which I have added from my profile about the curious badge why does it show 7

Comment: @codeczar Rand's answer explains that, essentially it looks to be because some don't count as you have deleted questions on the same day.

Comment: Thanks @thelethalcarrot

Comment: @codeczar I think 7 is the number of days you have which *do* count, but you still need to get an overall positive question record in order to get the badge.